# Does the WorkManager executes its PeriodicWork immediately after all constraints are met?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

It seems like I can't find any specific information about how the WorkManager handles its work after all constrains are met.

Let's say we've set up a WorkManager like this.

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
      .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
      .build()

val syncOnlyOnce = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PeriodicJob::class.java, updateInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
     .setConstraints(constraints)
     .build()
```

Let's say the updateInterval is 1h, network is connected and the work is executed. 
One hour has passed, the device is disconnected, the work is not executed.

What happens when the device reconnects? Does the WorkManager execute its work immediately (respectively the next possible execution window), or does it need to wait another period (e.g. ~1h)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WorkManager does not necessarily execute your work immediately.  As noted in the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), work is deferrable.  In situations like device doze mode, your work may not get executed right away.

Please see this page if you want to know more about your options: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/

Comment: Ok, but its defenitly scheduled for the next possible execution window?

Comment: yes @6rism0, it is scheduled for the next possible window. But, as stated in the docs as well, that depends on different factors, not only the connection (memory available, system load, etc)

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say the updateInterval is 1h, network is connected and the work
>   is executed. One hour has passed, the device is disconnected, the work
>   is not executed.

Android system makes sure that on the first moment the constraints meet, your WorkManager will start execution. You have to trust the Android team for this but honestly looks well tested. It also happens when you reboot the device, the WorkManager just "magically" reappears.

You will have certain moments when Android could kill your background worker though, but that's pretty rare. It could happen for example when you force stop your app from settings.

I think I have had some seconds delay for this case, but happens only on my OnePlus device.

Comment: Thanks! In the past I experienced some issues with the WorkManager in combination with some OS's of various (mostly asian) smartphone manufractures e.g. OnePlus, Huawei, etc. is there any possible solution to prevent this?

Comment: AFAIK One Plus had a bug that killed background processes I know nothing else, even about the others :)